# TreeViewItems displaying all the same text in wpf TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have a WPF application which creates a number of `TreeViewItems` and adds them to my `TreeView` during startup.  The Issue I am having is that when the window is loaded all of the `TreeViewItems` have the same header text.  I was getting the same issue when adding new items to the `TreeView` while the app was open, but I was able to fix that issue by adding `UpdateLayout()` after I added the item to the `TreeView`.  `treeView.Items,Add(item)`.  When I tried doing the same fix for when I add the items during startup the problem was not fixed.  Is there a issue with the `UpdateLayout()` method that is not allowing it to update each item so that they have different headers.

my `TreeView` is using an `ItemTemplate` which is defined below.

```
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:Name="datatemplate">
                            <StackPanel x:Name="stackpanel" Orientation="Horizontal" DataContext="{StaticResource ItemHeader}" >
                                <CheckBox x:Name="checkbox_treeview" IsChecked="{Binding Path=ischecked, Mode=OneWay}" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}}" Checked="treeView_AfterCheck" Unchecked="treeView_AfterCheck"/>
                                <Image x:Name="image_treeview" Width="16"/>
                                <local:WPFEditableTextBlock x:Name="label_TreeView" Text="{Binding Path=headertext}" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}}"  LostFocus="treeView_AfterLabelEdit"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

When I create the new `TreeViewItems` to be added to `myTreeView` I create a new `TreeViewItem` and add a `Style` to it that has a corresponding `Template`.

```
<Style x:Key="TreeViewItemStyle" TargetType="TreeViewItem"> <!--Selected Item Style -->
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel x:Name="stackpanel" Orientation="Horizontal" DataContext="{StaticResource ItemHeader}" >
                            <CheckBox x:Name="checkbox_treeview" IsChecked="{Binding Path=ischecked, Mode=OneWay}" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}}" Checked="treeView_AfterCheck" Unchecked="treeView_AfterCheck"/>
                            <Image x:Name="image_treeview" Source="node.png" Width="16" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}}" />
                            <local:WPFEditableTextBlock x:Name="label_TreeView"  Text="{Binding Path=headertext}" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}}"  LostFocus="treeView_AfterLabelEdit"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <EventSetter Event="TreeViewItem.DragOver"  Handler="treeView_DragOver"/>
            <EventSetter Event="TreeViewItem.Drop" Handler="treeView_Drop"/>
            <EventSetter Event="TreeViewItem.MouseMove" Handler="treeView_MouseMove"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="local:TreeViewDropHighlighter.IsPossibleDropTarget" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Also my `Style` is binded to my `ItemHeader` class which is how I manipulate the text of the headers.

```
 public class ItemHeader
{            
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the header text of the TreeViewItem
    /// </summary>
    public string headertext { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// gets or sets the checkbox for the TreeViewItem
    /// </summary>
    public bool ischecked { get; set; }
}
```

Lastly, when I am debugging and I go through my code that adds the `TreeViewItem` to the `TreeView` the `TreeView.Items` property shows that the headers are different text but when the window is displayed they all have the same header text.

I understand this is a complicated and weird question and I probably didn't explain it that well, but I'm super stuck, any advice would be helpful.

Comment: What is the text value they all have?

Comment: the text value they all have is equal to the last item in the `TreeView`. so if the items I wanted to add were  "a b c d". they would display as " d d d d"

Comment: They are all still unique `TreeViewItems` though.  It is Just the text that is being copied across them.

Comment: How does itemheader get into the treeview items?

Comment: You should be binding the itemssource of your treeview to a collection of some sort that in turn contains a collection of children. Then using a hierarchicaldatatemplate to give you actual treeviewitems in the treeview.

Comment: @Andy I tried doing it that way a while ago, but I ran into some other issues with another part of my app that made me not want to do it that way. The way I've Implemented it here works correctly for when I drag/drop the items into the `TreeView` and when I do a "file" "Open" to get the items in the `TreeView`, Its just when I am adding during the start up of the app where the text issues occurs.  I would like to debug just this section than rewriting all three sections.

Comment: If you are somehow using the same item then of course when you debug it will appear to have the current value at each stage. Download Snoop if you don't have it already. Fire it up and drag one of the sight things over your running app. Mouse over your items and press CTL+Shift. That'll highlight the relevant object in your snoop window. Take a look at the datacontext and see what you have there.

Comment: So I think my `TreeViewItem`s have the same `DataContext`